# 4 Person Peg Board Game?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image: 4 Person Peg Board Game]

Anyone have any idea what the game is called?

Comment: Are you certain that it is a 4-person game, and not a 2-person game?

Comment: Not really! Just guessing from the way it is set up.

Comment: Was the person who gave or sold it to you unable to give you any provenance information at all; for example, country of origin, age?

Comment: I purchased it at a Church Yard Sale in Punta Gorda, FL.

Comment: It appears that there are pegs of only one colour; a game would have different coloured pegs. I would guess that it is not a game at all, but rather a knitting board.

Comment: Robert Miller, I wondered that but couldn't find anything like that either.

Comment: It could be a single player game if all the pegs are a single color

Comment: The pegs are not colored and it has been a mystery search trying to figure it out.

Comment: With 54 holes and - apparently - only 8 pegs of one color, I would guess that it is a solve-this-puzzle kind solitaire game - **if** it is a game at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the object is not a game board, but a knitting board.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a flower loom for knitting/crocheting, not a game at all.

See for example [image] from https://www.prym.com/en/flower-loom-624156?c=5726